# Задержка вызова Activity после Splash Screen

Tags: java, android, activity

Здравствуйте.

Суть проблемы такова, что между `SplashScreen`, который показывается при запуске программы, и `Activity`, запускающейся после него, есть довольно большая задержка.

Т.е. после начального экрана приложение сворачивается, показывается меню телефона, а потом через секунд 2-5 открывается сама `Activity`.

Честно говоря, в самом начале все работало нормально, но после изменения кода поведение поменялось, и уже пару дней не могу понять, в чем проблема.

Сам код `SplashActivity` (он не особо большой, поэтому решил привести его полностью).

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
private ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tryToConnect();
    finish();
}

private void tryToConnect(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (preferences.getString("Login","").equals("") || preferences.getString("Password","").equals("")){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
        finish();
    } else {
        if (hasConnection()) {
            valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    userList = Globals.Downloads.getVerifiedUserList(dataSnapshot);

                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SplashActivity.this);
                    for (User user : userList)
                        if (user.getLogin().equals(preferences.getString("Login", "")))
                            signIn(user);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка в работе базы данных. Обратитесь к администратору компании или разработчику", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
        } else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Нет подключения к интернету", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void signIn(User user){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вход выполнен", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("allowNotifications", false))
        startService(new Intent(this, MessagingService.class));

    Globals.currentUser = user;
    databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, AcceptedTicketsActivity.class));
}

private boolean hasConnection() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);
    } catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return false;
}
}
```

В манифесте он объявлен так:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Стиль:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

Пробовал химичить с методом `finish()`, но результатов это никаких не дало.

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче говоря, повозился с этим всем. Заодно исправил свои ошибки в самом классе. В принципе, добился желаемого результата: `SplashActivity` висит прямо до момента открытия следующей `Activity`.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tryToConnect();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
}

private void tryToConnect(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (preferences.getString("Login","").equals("") || preferences.getString("Password","").equals("")){
        showSignInActivity();
    } else {
        if (hasConnection()) {
            valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    ArrayList<User> userList = Globals.Downloads.getVerifiedUserList(dataSnapshot);
                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SplashActivity.this);
                    checkVerificationData(userList, preferences.getString("Login", ""), preferences.getString("Password", ""));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка в работе базы данных. Обратитесь к администратору компании или разработчику", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SplashActivity.this.finish();
                }
            };
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Нет подключения к интернету", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showSignInActivity();
        }
    }
}

private void showSignInActivity(){
    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
    SplashActivity.this.finish();
}

private void signIn(User user){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вход выполнен", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("allowNotifications", false))
        startService(new Intent(this, MessagingService.class));

    Globals.currentUser = user;
    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, AcceptedTicketsActivity.class));
    SplashActivity.this.finish();
}

private void checkVerificationData(ArrayList<User> userList, String login, String password) {
    int i = 0;
    while (!login.equals(userList.get(i).getLogin()) && ++i < userList.size());
    if (i >= userList.size()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Логин и/или пароль введен неверно. Повторите попытку", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        showSignInActivity();
    }
    else if (login.equals(userList.get(i).getLogin()) && password.equals(userList.get(i).getPassword()))
        signIn(userList.get(i));
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Логин и/или пароль введен неверно. Повторите попытку", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        showSignInActivity();
    }
}

private boolean hasConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)SplashActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
}
```

Стиль поменял на это (забыл parent указать)

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сдается мне что проверять таким брутальным способом соединение с инетом не есть очень хорошо. Да и заклинанию `ipProcess.waitFor()` не место в основном потоке.
Попробуйте поискать более продвинутую практику проверки соединения, начните [отсюда](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

Comment: Возможно, конечно, это одна из причин подобного поведения `SplashActivity`, но даже после замены проверки подключения на то, что представлено в документации, задержка открытия следующей `Activity` все равно присутствует. Думаю, есть что-то другое, что я упускаю из вида.